# Setting value to defaults Layer properties using PyQGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, layers, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3, qgis-python-console

I have a vector layer, how to set defaults value in fields from the Python console.

```
Layer Properties / Attributes Form / Defaults |
```

In option: 
Default value `|______________|`

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [`QgsDefaultValue class`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDefaultValue.html) which allows you to enter default values or expressions for specific fields based on their index:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('ID')
layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(idx, QgsDefaultValue('3*4'))
```